# Converting enum to enum via int in C++

Tags: c++, enums

Is it valid to convert an enum to a different enum via int conversion, like illustrated below ? 
It looks like gcc for x64 has no problem with it, but is it something to expect with other compilers and platforms as well ?

What happens when `a` equals `A_third` and has no equivalent in `enum_B` ?

```
enum enum_A {
    A_first = 0,
    A_second,
    A_third
};

enum enum_B {
    B_first = 0,
    B_second
};

enum_A a = A_first;
enum_B b;

b = enum_B(int(a));
```

Comment: *What happens when a equals A_third and has no equivalent in enum_B ?* What would you like to happen. Surely you realise that what you are attempting is fundamentally wrong. What are you trying to achieve here.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, Are you *sure* it's UB? We're not talking about the stronger enumeration types in C++11.

Comment: My understanding is, that if it doesn't overflow the implied integral type of the enum, then you get an unlabelled enumeration value; and that's well-defined.

Comment: @Bathsheba You're probably right, and I don't have the specification readily available at the moment so I can't check, so I'll retract my comments.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : Yes, I realize this is awfully wrong. I'm just curious as to what should actually happen during execution: will the program crash with an error, will it fail silently and continue with an unpredictable value, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be careful when doing this, due to some edge cases:

From the C++11 standard (§7.2,6):

> For an enumeration whose underlying type is not fixed, the underlying
>   type is an integral type that can represent all the enumerator values
>   defined in the enumeration. If no integral type can represent all the
>   enumerator values, the enumeration is ill-formed. It is
>   implementation-defined which integral type is used as the underlying
>   type except that the underlying type shall not be larger than int
>   unless the value of an enumerator cannot fit in an int or unsigned
>   int.

This means that it is possible that an `enum` is a larger type than an `int` so the conversion from `enum` to `int` *could* fail with undefined results.

Subject to the above, it *is* possible to convert an `int` to an `enum` that results in an enumerator value that the `enum` does not specify explicitly. Informally, you can think of an `enum` as being an integral type with a few values explicitly defined with labels.